# Indexes precision in large JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on an algorithmic task with (relatively) big arrays and values in them. To be more specific, arrays have 100000 elements where all elements are integers and each element can be as high as 1000000000. So, the question is can JavaScript return wrong element on a given index or vice versa? I suppose so because as it revealed, it looses precision with integers multiplication and other operations after they grow higher than 10 to the power 18.

Comment: Your stated highest value is far from 10^18.

Comment: Check `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant in javascript. It's 9007199254740991 (~9 quadrillion) so I don't think that will be an issue

Comment: Have you even tried it yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

No it won't return the wrong element. Indexes are irrelevant to the Math class

Comment: nice ! Thanks for the reference

Comment: Duplicates should be commented and (when you can) close-voted, not *answered*.